# HttpResponseMessage from WebAPI from angular http post call

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a UI project , which is an Angular JS project and Web API project and i am new to Angular. I am calling a login method of API controller which does the DB check and its sending OK message. But its going to error part of Angular http promise call. What can be the possible reasons? This is the API Call

```
function AutenticateUser(input) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: input,
            url: config.serviceUrl + config.loginUrl,
            transformRequest: function (input) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in input)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(input[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            userInfo = {
                accessToken: result.data.access_token,
                userName: input.username
            };
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Does the accept header has to do anything with it?

Comment: What is in the error? Note that you never resolve the promise

Comment: Are you sure the login API accepts URL encoding? It is better to use `Content-Type: 'application/json'`. There are security issues with URLencoding.

Comment: hi george the code was already written, i will change and will let you know. The data gets passed to controller and its returning a success response